# Solution to the convoluted integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

A have the following equation:

$$f(a)=\int_0^ag(x)f(x)\,dx,$$

where $g(x)$ is a known function. Is there any solution to $f(a)$ just in terms of $g$?

Comment: Some arbitrary function.

Comment: Is the equation supposed to hold for all $a$ (in the domain of $f$)?

Comment: just saw there is no convolution here. $f'(x) = g(x) f(x)$ so that $\frac{f'}{f} = g, \ \ln f(x) = \int g(x)dx + C,\  f(x) = e^{\int g(x) dx + C}$

Comment: Something weird happens when $x=0$.  I guess that $g(x)$ must not be *nice* around $x=0$ for $f$ to be nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

Generally,

$$ \int_0^af^\prime(x)\,dx=f(a)-f(0) $$

so if $$ f(a)=\int_0^a g(x)f(x)\,dx $$

and $f(0)=0$ and furthermore if it is generally true that

$$  f(x)=\int_0^xg(t)f(t)\,dt$$

then one might conclude that

$$f^\prime(x)=g(x)f(x)$$

which implies

$$ \dfrac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}=g(x)$$

or

$$ \left(\ln(f(x)\right)^\prime=g(x)$$

so that

$$f(x)=\exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x g(t)\,dt\right)$$

for some $x_0$ in which case one could say

$$ f(a)=\int_0^ag(x)\exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x g(t)\,dt\right)\,dx  $$

Comment: I'll have to learn to type $\LaTeX$ faster.

Comment: Not sure if you should write $$f(a)=\int_0^a\,g(x)\,\exp\left(\int_{\color{red}{0}}^x\,g(t)\,\text{d}t\right)\,\text{d}x\,.$$  The zero in red causes a problem.  For example, when $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we see that $f$ must be the zero function, but your equation yields a nonzero solution.

Comment: i just submitted a correction for this.

Comment: @FrancescoAlem.  Just came back from lunch. Will try to correct it myself before considering other corrections.

Comment: @Batominovski See previous comment.

Comment: it's still not correct.. $$f(x)=f(x_0)\exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x g(t)\,dt\right)$$
you must do a definite integral on the diff. eq. to find this.

Comment: There is actually a deeper problem with this approach. Nothing in the question says that generally $f(x)=\int_0^xf(t)g(t)\,dt$ only that for some particular $a$,  $f(a)=\int_0^af(t)g(t)\,dt$

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. But $f(x_0)=1$.

Comment: right... thanks